# Not able to add new item in wordpress home page

Tags: php, visual-editor, footer

Recently i changed my WordPress folder from demo to main folder so i did changes in `wp_options` db table.

But now when i add any new item in home page. It is not allowing me to do that. It is not showing any error, but when i update page. new added items are not showing there.

I tried by removing few items from top of page and after that if i add new item it takes changes. So, I think the problem is with memory of page. Is there anything like page memory in WordPress. If it is than how can i increase page memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try undoing your database modification. As far as I can tell you can rename the parent folder to anything you like without changing how the site functions.